# Salesforce DX Trailhead Error

Tags: trailhead, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm working on Salesforce Dx [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/sfdx_get_started/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_create_app) . When creating Scratch org using command

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a GeoAppScratch
```

I'm getting this error:

> ERROR:  No defaultdevhubusername org found.
>   Try this:
>   Run the "sfdx force:auth" commands with --setdefaultdevhubusername to connect to a Dev Hub org and set it as your default Dev Hub.
>   Run "force:org:list" to see a list of locally registered orgs.
>   Run "sfdx force:config:set defaultdevhubusername=" to set your default Dev Hub username.

Even I tried to set default Org using below command

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias DevHub
```

But I'm getting this error:

> ERROR:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\content-type\index.js'.

In trailhead creating scratch org is given as 3rd command, I'm not sure if I need to login in DevHub or not, as there is no other information available in trailhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today I again tried to Authorize Developer Hub (Dev Hub) org, set it as default by using below command:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias DevHub
```

After authorizing dev hub, I was able to create scratch org.